Multiple if condition in Cloudformation

  //  frontendSubdomain:
Type: String
Default: test-ui

CloudFrontDistribution:
Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    WebACLId: !GetAtt WebACL.Arn
    Aliases:
      !If
      - NonTestEnv
      - - !If
          - OnlyPrd
          - - !Join
              - ""
              - - Ref: frontendSubdomain
                - ".ui.com"
            - !Join
              - ""
              - - Ref: frontendSubdomain
                - "{{resolve:ssm:/"
                - Ref: Env
                - "Name:{LATEST}}}"
          -
          - - !Join
              - ""
              - - Ref: frontendSubdomain
                - !Sub -${EnvironmentParameter}.vermontmutual.com
              - !Join
                - ""
                - - Ref: frontendSubdomain
                  - .
                  - "{{resolve:ssm:/"
                  - Ref: Env
                  - "Name:{LATEST}}}"
      -
      - - !Join
          - ""
          - - Ref: frontendSubdomain
            - .
            - "{{resolve:ssm:/"
            - Ref: Env
            - "Name:{LATEST}}}"
    Comment: !Sub Cloudfront Distribution for ${Env} Environment


I am getting an Issue "/DistributionConfig/Aliases/Fn::If/1/0/Fn::If/2] 'null' values are not allowed in templates" It would be very helpfule if someone find the issue on this code.

Please fix indentation in the question for your code. Otherwise its not clear what is your actual code - the one with incorrect indentation on SO?
